# Installation and configuration of stand-alone GeoWebCache

Tags: geowebcache

I recently installed the stand-alone version of GeoWebCache 1.6.0 and deployed it on a Tomcat 7.0 container.

The official documentation tells to modify "geowebcache.xml" in the following location ..

```
The main configuration file for GeoWebCache is geowebcache.xml. 
It is located inside the the main GeoWebCache application directory at 
WEB-INF/classes/geowebcache.xml.
```

But I couldn't find it anywhere in the "...\Tomcat7.0\webapps\geowebcache\" at all!

Also, I have an empty list of layers on the "demo" page on the geowebcache web admin. 
When I hit "Reload Configuration" button, it popped up a login box. I looked for username and password in "user.properties" file following the instruction. But it only contains "geowebcache=secured,ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR".

What are the username and password should I use?

It just has a so bad documentation... ...

p.s. I don't have GeoServer installed yet. Does GeoWebCache mean to work in stand-alone? I just want to cache an external WMS. Where do I find "GeoWebCache.xml" and where are all cached files stored in Tomcat?

Comment: They try to tell the default username/password in http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/security.html: `Change geowebcache to your desired username and secured to your password of choice. It is recommended that you use only ASCII characters`

Comment: Thanks. The reloading worked. But there is not a single layer actually loaded...

Comment: Have you tried seeding it? What do you mean by loaded? to a Client Browser? Have you connected it to your GeoServer Layers? Perhaps posting exactly what steps you have done in your question will help us figure out what your problem is, and what server are you using?

Comment: I don't have GeoServer installed, thinking GWC is meant to work in stand-alone, doesn't it?

Comment: What are you trying to use it to display? Where are you map tiles coming from? They have to come from somewhere? GeoWebCache does not come with any maps .. just some demo layers. It would help if you explained exactly WHAT you are trying to achieve .. I suggest you update you question with more information on that, what servers you are running and what maps you are trying to display .. extremely difficult to give you any answer without knowing this information .. in for the XML file, it is dependent on what server environment you are running ..

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a cascading WMS Service? have you tried this? GeoWebCache comes preconfigured with three layers. To view them, navigate to your GeoWebCache demo page at http://GEOWEBCACHE_URL/demo (often this is http://localhost:8080/geowebcache/demo). Click on any of the links next to the OpenLayers column.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark said, standalone GWC will not work without Geoserver (that means web map server). By default, GWC (GeoWebCache) comes as integrated plug in with Geoserver installation files. Stand alone GWC means you can also set up GWC separately and configure to work in sync with installed Geoserver based on your requirements for clustering or so.

Install Geoserver and then configure GeoWebCache to serve wms maps faster. GeoWebCache is a tile caching plugin, which has dependancy to have Geoserver installed to to serve maps through GWC.